# How to know if a DateTime is between a DateRange in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date-range

I need to know if a Date is between a DateRange. I have three dates:

```cs
// The date range
DateTime startDate;
DateTime endDate;

DateTime dateToCheck;
```

The easy solution is doing a comparison, but is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: A smarter way then just checking if the date is between those dates?

Comment: So what is smarter than an easy solution?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Nope, doing a simple comparison looks good to me:

```
return dateToCheck >= startDate && dateToCheck < endDate;
```

Things to think about though:

- `DateTime` is a somewhat odd type in terms of time zones. It could be UTC, it could be "local", it could be ambiguous. Make sure you're comparing apples with apples, as it were.
- Consider whether your start and end points should be inclusive or exclusive. I've made the code above treat it as an inclusive lower bound and an exclusive upper bound.

Comment: Yes. Making sure that the `DateTime`s you compare are of the same kind(UTC/Local) is important. With different kinds the raw time will be compared instead of converting both to a common kind.

Comment: `return startDate <= dateToCheck && dateToCheck < endDate` seems slightly more readable.

Comment: @MauricioMorales: It depends; some people find it easier to read "the bit that's varying" (the date to check) being on the left hand side consistently. That's what I tend to do. I can see the advantages of the "in chronological order" approach too, but I think I'd personally prefer the way I've got it.

Comment: @MauricioMorales when deciding which side of a comparison to write first, I always pick the object being checked, instead of the value it is being compared to. That seems most logical to me. So in this case, where `dateToCheck` is the object being checked, I would write it first (on both sides of the `&&`) like @JonSkeet did.

Answer (score 73):

Usually I create [Fowler's Range](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Range.html) implementation for such things.

```
public interface IRange<T>
{
    T Start { get; }
    T End { get; }
    bool Includes(T value);
    bool Includes(IRange<T> range);
}

public class DateRange : IRange<DateTime>         
{
    public DateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get; private set; }

    public bool Includes(DateTime value)
    {
        return (Start <= value) && (value <= End);
    }

    public bool Includes(IRange<DateTime> range)
    {
        return (Start <= range.Start) && (range.End <= End);
    }
}
```

Usage is pretty simple:

```
DateRange range = new DateRange(startDate, endDate);
range.Includes(date)
```

Comment: Just a silly observation, doesn't the constructor need to ensure that start is less than end, if it doesn't, it would break the logic ... especially on the Includes(IRange<DateTime> range)

Comment: Man this is such an good solution it even work with LINQ. Like so: 
var valueFromVacationsList =vacationBookingsForThisMonth.FirstOrDefault(s => (s.Id == currentUser.Id)&&new DateRange(s.StartDateTime, s.EndDateTime).Includes(itemDate));

Answer (score 60):

You could use extension methods to make it a little more readable:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool InRange(this DateTime dateToCheck, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return dateToCheck >= startDate && dateToCheck < endDate;
    }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
dateToCheck.InRange(startDate, endDate)
```

Comment: nice approach, though I'd use `IsInRange()` as the function name

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
return (dateTocheck >= startDate && dateToCheck <= endDate);
```

Answer (score 5):

I’ve found the following library to be the most helpful when doing any kind of date math. I’m still amazed nothing like this is part of the .Net framework.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Comment: I agree. I cannot believe .NET has no native date math assemblies. Thanks for sharing the library

Comment: I used the Time Period library for a project that created schedules for when electronic signs were supposed to display images and it was a real time-saver.  Heck, I can't imagine having completed that project w/o the Time Period library.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from Sergey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4781727/197591), I think this more generic version is more in line with Fowler's `Range` idea, and resolves some of the issues with that answer such as being able to have the `Includes` methods within a generic class by constraining `T` as `IComparable<T>`. It's also immutable like what you would expect with types that extend the functionality of other value types like `DateTime`.

```
public struct Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public Range(T start, T end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public T Start { get; }

    public T End { get; }

    public bool Includes(T value) => Start.CompareTo(value) <= 0 && End.CompareTo(value) >= 0;

    public bool Includes(Range<T> range) => Start.CompareTo(range.Start) <= 0 && End.CompareTo(range.End) >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants it as a Validator

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace GROOT.Data.Validation;

internal class DateRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string EndDate;
    public string StartDate;

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return (DateTime)value >= DateTime.Parse(StartDate) && (DateTime)value <= DateTime.Parse(EndDate);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
[DateRange(
    StartDate = "01/01/2020",
    EndDate = "01/01/9999",
    ErrorMessage = "Property is outside of range")
    ]
```