# How to validate dates falling not occupied in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

What I want to check date ranges falling in my provided date or not.
For example I have a table with "`FROM`" and "`TO`" dates.

I just want to check that given date doesn't fall in dates in database.

**Data in Database**

```
FromDate  and TODate 

1 Aug 2012  ------  4 Aug 2012

5 Aug 2012 ------   11 Aug 2012

12 Aug 2012 ------  15 Aug 2012
```

Example From and To Dates

```
FromDate      and      ToDate 

1 Aug 2012 ------   2 Aug 2012  **Should Return INVALID**

5 Aug 2012  ------  11 Aug 2012 **Should Return INVALID**

10 Aug 2012 ------   10 Aug 2012  **Should Return VALID**

15 Aug 2012  ------ 15 Aug 2012 **Should Return INVALID**
```

Can someone give any idea?

I am using `LINQ` to `SQL` in querying from database.

EDIT: just want to make sure that my TO and From dates dont conflicts with the dates in Database

Comment: I don't understand when it's valid and when it's not.

Comment: please share some code for us to help you

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question or provide some additional information/ code? I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Take a look on [range implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4781727/470005)

Comment: Updated. 10 aug is valid as this is not falling in any dates in database

Comment: Well then your title is misleading coz there is no range here, just need to filter on the values which are not available in either of the columns

Comment: Updated. I need some solution please

Comment: Is 15 Aug 2012 - 16 Aug 2012 Valid or Invalid?

Comment: 15 Aug 2012 - 16 Aug 2012 is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the intervals start and end point is correct, do not check it. We examine the existing interval intersects whether the interval in question:

```
void Main()
{

var ExistIntervals = new HashSet<Interval>();
//1 Aug 2012 4 Aug 2012
//5 Aug 2012 11 Aug 2012
//12 Aug 2012 15 Aug 2012
ExistIntervals.Add(new Interval { From = new DateTime(2012, 8, 1), 
                                  To = new DateTime(2012, 8, 4) });
ExistIntervals.Add(new Interval { From = new DateTime(2012, 8, 5), 
                                  To = new DateTime(2012, 8, 11) });
ExistIntervals.Add(new Interval { From = new DateTime(2012, 8, 12), 
                                  To = new DateTime(2012, 8, 15) });

var QueryIntervals = new HashSet<Interval>();
//1 Aug 2012 2 Aug 2012 INVALID
//5 Aug 2012 11 Aug 2012 INVALID
//10 Aug 2012 10 Aug 2012 VALID
//15 Aug 2012 15 Aug 2012 INVALID
QueryIntervals.Add(new Interval { From = new DateTime(2012, 8, 1), 
                                  To = new DateTime(2012, 8, 2) });
QueryIntervals.Add(new Interval { From = new DateTime(2012, 8, 5), 
                                  To = new DateTime(2012, 8, 11) });
QueryIntervals.Add(new Interval { From = new DateTime(2012, 8, 10), 
                                  To = new DateTime(2012, 8, 10) });
QueryIntervals.Add(new Interval { From = new DateTime(2012, 8, 15), 
                                  To = new DateTime(2012, 8, 15) });

var result = QueryIntervals.Where( x=> !ExistIntervals.Any(
                                         y=>(y.From <= x.From && x.From <= y.To)
                                         || (y.From <= x.To && x.To<=y.To)
                                                          )
                                 );
result.Dump();                                                         

}

public class Interval
{
  public DateTime From { get; set; }
  public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

**The result is an empty set.**

(the result is an empty set, since 10 Aug 2012th in this interval: 5 Aug 2012 ------ 11 Aug 2012)

You can test with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

**Update**:

Suppose that the table name "CompaitnDates", the context name "CompaitnContext" and to determine the interval of two variables: "checkFrom", "checkTo".

```
var checkFrom = new DateTime(2012, 8, 10);
var checkTo = new DateTime(2012, 8, 10);
var db = new CompaitnContext();
```

then the test may be as follows:

```
var isValid = !db.CompaitnDates.Any(
                                    y=>(y.From <= checkFrom && checkFrom <= y.To)
                                    || (y.From <= checkTo && checkTo<=y.To)
                                   );
```

Comment: Didnt catch that, I have dates in Database. I just wanat to check this from database with LinqToSql

Comment: This line is your friend: var result = QueryIntervals.Where( x=> !ExistIntervals.Any(y=>(y.From <= x.From && x.From <= y.To) || (y.From <= x.To && x.To<=y.To))); Assuming that lists the intervals tested in "QueryIntervals" and the name of the existing intervals in EF "ExistIntervals". But if you give the name of the table and to use the tested interval, it may be that I can still help.

Comment: Table name is CompaitnDates

Comment: Great !! Done . thaks for helping. God bless you