# finding date between terms of dates

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an array of terms which have start-dates and end-dates. how can I find whether today falls between the terms. code is

```
  var termsforcurrentCalendar = UnitOfWork.SchoolTerms.Query().Where(x
  => x.SchoolCalendarId == currentCalendar.SchoolCalendarId).ToArray();

   var noOfTerms = termsforcurrentCalendar.Count();

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfTerms; i++)
   {
      if (DateTime.Today > termsforcurrentCalendar[i].EndDate)
      {
          if (i != noOfTerms)
       {
           if (DateTime.Today < termsforcurrentCalendar[i + 1].StartDate)
        {
           datetoBeChecked = termsforcurrentCalendar[i + 1].StartDate;
        }
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: today belongs to a term or falls between two terms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if a DateTime is between a DateRange in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781611/how-to-know-if-a-datetime-is-between-a-daterange-in-c-sharp)

Comment: if today falls between terms get the next terms first date

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it (green tick) :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var isTodayInTerm = termsforcurrentCalendar.Any(a =>DateTime.Today >= a.StartDate && DateTime.Today <= a.EndDate);

    if (!isTodayInTerm)
    {
        var firstAvailableDate = termsforcurrentCalendar.FirstOrDefault(z => z.StartDate > DateTime.Today);
        datetoBeChecked = firstAvailableDate.StartDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a bit of linq niceness:

```
var isTodayInTerm = termsforcurrentCalendar.Any(a => 
    DateTime.Today >= a.StartDate && DateTime.Today <= a.EndDate);
```

---

As per comment, to get the next term:

```
var nextTerm = termsforcurrentCalendar.OrderBy(a => a.StartDate).FirstOrDefault(a =>
    a.StartDate >= DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: if today falls between terms get the next terms first date

Comment: Please edit your question then, as the answer provided answers your question perfectly.

Comment: What if there are two terms with startdates more than the 'today' ?

Comment: @tariq Then it gets the first one.

Comment: @tariq If he has two starting on the same day then you cannot be certain of which will be selected - but the OP did not provide enough information to deal with this case.

Comment: i think that you should order the list first and then pick up the first one

Answer (score 0):

```
var isTodayInTerm = termsforcurrentCalendar.Any(a =>DateTime.Today >= a.StartDate && DateTime.Today <= a.EndDate);

if (!isTodayInTerm)
{
    var firstAvailableDate = termsforcurrentCalendar.OrderBy(a=>a.StartDate).FirstOrDefault(z => z.StartDate > DateTime.Today);
    datetoBeChecked = firstAvailableDate.StartDate;
}
```