# How can I ckeck that the current time is within a specific time range?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to compare that the current time is within a specific range. I've tried the following

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now; 
int Comaprestart = DateTime.Compare(currentTime, startTime);
int CompareEnd = DateTime.Compare(currentTime,endTime);
if ((Comaprestart >= 0) && (CompareEnd <= 0))
     LinkBtnQuiz.Enabled = true;
```

It doesn't work right. for example I have the end time equal '2014-06-08 13:30:00.000' and the current time equal '2014-06-08 13:12:00.000' but I get CompareEnd=1 while it should be -1 as the current time is earlier than the end time.

Any idea of what is causing the error??

Comment: `if (startTime < currentTime && currentTime < endTime)`

Comment: @MattBurland Still not working. The problem seems in comparing the current time with the end time! I have endTime = '2014-06-08 14:30:00.000' and currentTime = '2014-06-08 14:25:00.000'

Comment: @MattBurland Do you think that it matters if the system read the date time in 12 hours format? My system time is in 12 hors format

Comment: No. Date comparisions in the .NET framework work. It would be a pretty big deal if they didn't. Are you sure what you think the times are in those `DateTime` objects are correct? How do you populate them in the first place? Look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eKjruG). It works just fine. Are you sure your `DateTime` are all in the same time zone?

Comment: You're right. the Problem was in the format.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it easier:

```
if(currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime)
{
   LinkBtnQuiz.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and still have the same problem. The if return false!

Answer (score 0):

```
return dateToCheck >= startDate && dateToCheck < endDate;
```

Check this answer [How to know if a DateTime is between a DateRange in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781611/how-to-know-if-a-datetime-is-between-a-daterange-in-c-sharp)