# Match all rows on particular day using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

How would you find all rows in a table that have a time matching a particular day?

The SQL DataType for the column `Time` is `datetime`.

For example, let's say you want all rows from 9/20/2014 and the table column `Time` looks like this...`2014-09-20 17:02:05.903`

```
var query = from t in SomeTable
            where t.Time // don't know what goes here
            select t;
```

Comment: Is your Time column `datetime` type?

Comment: @greatbear302 Yes, the SQL DataType is `datetime`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this one:

```
// Define your startDate. In our case it would be 9/20/2014 00:00:00
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2014,09,20);

// Define your endDate. In our case it would be 9/21/2014 00:00:00
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);

// Get all the rows of SomeTable, whose Time is between startDate and endDate.
var query = from t in SomeTable
            where t.Time>= startDate and t.Time<=endDate
            select t;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void DoSomethingWithSomeTable(int day, int month, int year)
{
    var query = from t in SomeTable
                where t.Time.Date.Equals(new DateTime(year, month, day))
                select t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var query = from t in SomeTable
        where t.Time.Date == new DateTime(2014, 9, 20)
        select t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use extension methods to make it a little more readable:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool InRange(this DateTime dateToCheck, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return dateToCheck >= startDate && dateToCheck < endDate;
    }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
dateToCheck.InRange(startDate, endDate)
```

or

```
var start = new DateTime(2014, 9, 20);
dateToCheck.InRange(start, start.AddDays(1));
```

([this solution was found posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782362/3259125))