# C# Get Empty partion of the date time from List date time

Tags: c#, list, date, time

i have in c# this list of the Rendez-vous:

- ID            Date_Start                 Date_End

  1. 18/11/2016 08:00          18/11/2016 14:00
  2. 18/11/2016 09:00          18/11/2016 11:30
  3. 18/11/2016 14:00          18/11/2016 16:30
  4. 18/11/2016 17:30          18/11/2016 19:00

How I can check the part of time is busy or no ?
for exemple how to check the part time from 18/11/2016 11:30 to 18/11/2016 14:00 is busy ?

thanks for your Response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if a DateTime is between a DateRange in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781611/how-to-know-if-a-datetime-is-between-a-daterange-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @MacakM I think OP is actually looking for an overlap of date ranges, although it's unclear

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're looking for from your question. My interpretation is that you want to know whether a given range of dates overlaps with any range in your list. Here's the code to do that:

```
Rendezvous[] rendezvous = ... // you already have this
DateTime startTime = ... // e. g. 18/11/2016 11:30
DateTime endTime = ... // e. g. 18/11/2016 14:00
var isBusy = rendezvous.Any(r => !(endTime < r.Date_Start || startTime > r.Date_End));
```